# netbeans uploading website to server

Tags: java, netbeans

```
Cannot connect to server ***.***.**.*
(Cause: Could not parse response code.
Server Reply: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3)
```

I am trying to upload my web project in server now that i am running it perfectly in local host i want to try it in server if it look ok now. I am using Netbeans IDE but when i run the project it gives me that error above when try to check for server connection.In my run as field i chose `Remote Web Site ( Ftp, Sftp )`. what is the possible problem in this scenario? Question two is there a possibility that there will be a difference in local host and in server in term of function of code and look of the web

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to connect to a server from Netbeans (v8.2). Here's what I did to resolve the issue:

1. Right click on the project and select Properties.
2. Go to the Run Configuration section and click the Manage button next to Remote Connection.
3. In the dialog that comes up, make sure that the connection you are using is SFTP and not FTP (this is displayed next to the connection name on the left). If it's FTP, click the Add button to setup a new connection that uses SFTP.

This worked for me. I imagine it has to do with the server being configured to only allow certain connection types.